# Google Sites HTML box not allowing css transform to work

Tags: html, css, transform, sites

Why am I getting this error?

"css property transform has bad value: ==>skew(-5deg)<== rotate(-5deg)"

I'm trying to add HTML and CSS into an HTML Box but I keep getting errors about transforms in the CSS. I'd like to be able to use these transform effects on elements in my HTML. It works normally in a normal HTML page in the Google Chrome browser. Here's my link to the site I'm trying it on: https://sites.google.com/site/pghsguidance/home ... the HTML box is right under the "Freshman Newsletter" link. Here's my code for the HTML box:

```
<style>
    .box {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .box:before, .box:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 40%;
        height: 10px;
        content: ' ';
        left: 12px;
        bottom: 12px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
        transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: -1;
        /***** Transition *****/
        -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
        -moz-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
        -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
        -o-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.15s, opacity 0.15s linear;
    } 

    .box:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        left: auto;
        right: 12px;
        -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    }

    .box:hover:before, .box:hover:after {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }
</style>

<div class="box">
    <p>bam</p>
</div>
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `skewX(5deg)` or `skewY(5deg)` or both. There is no shorthand for `skew()`.

Comment: Why would it work outside of Google Sites then? Google sites still gives me errors when using skewX and skewY anyway.